# How long do the Minions live?

Tags: minions, minions-movie

At the very beginning of the Minions movie, we are introduced to Norbert, coming out of the water wearing nothing, realizing his nudity, and covering himself... inappropriately.  The voiceover states that he's a bit of an idiot.  This scene clearly takes place thousands of years ago.

Later in the movie, we see a photograph set in Kevin's wallet that includes Norbert, with his name at the bottom of the photo, and text (or possibly speech - I forget which) saying he's an idiot (or some similar term - again, imperfect memory).

While it's only one character trait, it's the only Minion to have this particular trait applied.  It seems to be intended as a repeated joke about the character, which only works if it's the same character.  The character also has the exact same name. While it is possible that there are two Norberts, and both are idiots, this would break the intended joke, it seems much more likely that they are intended to be one and the same.

Similarly, other minions seem to exist both thousands of years ago and in 'modern' day. For example, Kevin appears to be looking over the edge of the cliff after the boulder... finished, and is back later in the 'modern' part of the movie.

This implies that Minions live a very long time.  How long do Minions live - what is their life span?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the dinosaurs lived slightly longer ago than a few thousands years ago.

Comment: :-) understatement. Also trying to avoid edits due to spoilers.

Comment: @Richard - That sounds like blasphemy.

Comment: The reason they could be more than 200 million years old is because it's implied that they've existed sense the beginning of time.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107457/4918 "Can minions actually die?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can minions actually die?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107457/can-minions-actually-die)

Comment: Not all forms of ancient evil look Lovecraftian.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the movie, minions are effectively (biologically) immortal unless they are killed through being an idiot.

The main characters are seen to predate a T-Rex, aging them at around 200 million years old or older, in the humanoid shape they are most known for. They do not age, and have not been shown as sickly, aside from a depressive state from having a lack of a Villain to minion for.

Comment: Is there any point in time where this is stated, or other evidence beyond that in the question? I mean, they seem to have a long lifespan, but I never noticed evidence that they can't die a natural death.

Comment: @atk their shown lifespan is roughly atleast 230 Million years. No signs of old age or sickness. That makes them *effectively* immortal.

Comment: Can you explain where you got 200 and 230 million years? According to Wikipedia, Tyrannosaurus rex lived from about 68 to 66 million years ago.

Comment: Humanoid shape? What kind of humans do you hang out with? Aren't they more of a… bananoid shape? Or a tic-tacoid shape, perhaps.

Comment: @Hypnosifl the first dinosaurs appeared in the Triassic. Maybe he just mixed up the years, because (regardless of what Hollywood makes us believe) tyrannosaurus are definitely from the Cretaceous period.

Answer (score 7):

According to screenwriter [Brian Lynch on Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/brianlynch/status/1392308547124297728), they are immortal:

> **Ed Zitron** Can Minions die?
>
> **Brian Lynch** Hi Ed! No.
>
> **Tom McK** Just to be clear here, what would happen if I hit a Minion repeatedly with a very large, sharp, and heavy axe?
>
> **Brian** *The axe would break.*

(lightly copyedited)

[image]

Comment: Being physically immune to harm and being biologically immortal are typically similar but distinct traits. I like this answer but it does not offer a distinction.

Comment: @Skooba "Can Minions Die?" Brian: "No". Sounds like immortality to me.