# Can minions actually die?

Tags: despicable-me, minions, minions-movie

They seem to be able to live forever or at least an incredibly long time. They befriend the biggest threats towards their life, they can also survive in space.

**Can a minion die? Under what circumstances?**

Comment: I wish they would.

Comment: Related, not dupe; [How long do the Minions live?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96539/how-long-do-the-minions-live?rq=1)

Comment: @Valorum considering they both share answers, why are they not dupes?

Comment: @TheAsh - Immortality and functional immortality are different things.

Comment: @Valorum isn't there a policy if the answers are the same it's a dupe even if the questions are the same?

Comment: @TheAsh - This is one of those cases where the questions should probably be *merged*. Each has good answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The minions themselves seem to think so.** When one of their number appears to have exploded, caps are doffed and tears begin to flow profusely.

Evidently the death of a minion is a rare event (we've seen them survive an awful lot unscathed) but one which provokes a strong community response.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

According to screenwriter Brian Lynch, the answer is no:

> **Ed Zitron** Can Minions die?
>
> **Brian Lynch** Hi Ed! No.
>
> **Tom McK** Just to be clear here, what would happen if I hit a Minion repeatedly with a very large, sharp, and heavy axe?
>
> **Brian** *The axe would break.*

(lightly copyedited)

https://mobile.twitter.com/brianlynch/status/1392308547124297728

[image]

Comment: It would probably be best to copy the text in rather than solely an image of the text.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot will do as soon as I get to a computer. Can this site embed tweets?

Comment: It can't unfortunately.